# ¿Cómo evitar que mi programa sea plagiado?

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de "proteger" mi código para que no pueda ser decompilado (Hace unos días vi un .jar que ponía: "//Internal error" al intentar decompilarlo)

Comment: Desde que existe china no se puede (y creo que china existió ya antes de la informática). Puedes hacerlo difícil, pero no lo puedes evitar 100%.

Comment: hahahahaahahaha @StefanNolde me hiciste el día con la respuesta y ahora con el comentario, hahahahahaaaaaaaaaa xD!!!

Comment: Dice la moraleja "Cuando veas un nombre chino _donde sea_, corre".

Comment: @NaCl mi comentario en ningún aspecto apuntó a despreciar los chinos. Este pueblo tiene tanta historia y nos regaló tanta cultura que pienso que tienen todo el derecho de copiar lo que sea sin sentirse mal ;) En realidad les agrado que demuestran tan eficiente que el concepto de proteger información o conocimiento esta fallado en si.

Comment: @StefanNolde No me he referido a lo que su comentario menciona ;). Es que son buenos para lo que sea, no he visto algo que aún no puedan hacer, claro, nosotros podemos hacer igual, pero es muy diferente.

Answer (score 21):

La respuesta TLDR; es: **NO**. Siempre hay y siempre va haber una forma de decompilar tu código, lo único que puedes hacer es hacerlo más difícil.
La industria trata de crear formas artificiales con certificados y números de series de la cpu (vea "dongles").

**En la informática no se paga para lo que hiciste ayer, pero para lo que te creen que eres capaz de hacer hoy día para mañana.**

Eso dicho, ofrezco compartir un poco de experiencia sobre el tema de derechos digitales (que ya sabemos como funcionan en audio y vídeo).

**¿Que métodos hay de proteger mi obra y que nivel de seguro son?**

**1) Software como servicio (software as a service)**

Lejos lo mejor. No abres tu código, no abres tu ejecutable, manejas todo el sistema donde corre, y "solamente" tienes que asegurarte que no te entran en tu sistema (pregunta a los grandes jugadores como les resultó eso cuando se encontró el **BUG** en openssl).

**2) Dongles**

Deja tu producto de ciencia de cohete acceder a un dispositivo que valida tu producto constantemente con criptografía dura al nivel de hardware. La gente que quieren copiar eso van a frustrarse con los gastos para reproducir el dispositivo que dejaste fabricar en masa. Aun con productos interesante lo hacen. O simplemente hacen un *crack* de tu software que ignora el dongle.

**3) Código ofuscado**

En serio? Código no documentado no es mantenible, código no mantenible no tiene valor - es código desechable. Para que invertir tiempo entonces en ofuscar código si ya no escribiste documentación de API?

Probablemente se me han olvidado otros métodos esotéricos de "proteger" código, pero el principio siempre queda lo mismo.

**Otro aspecto del tema es:**

**¿Mi código vale ser protegido?**

En mi experiencia, ningún código vale ser "protegido". Algoritmos podría ser otro tema, pero en eso entremos en la pregunta si el esfuerzo vale la pena. Miremos las alternativas:

**1) Soy EL experto en el tema y trabajé años en mi algoritmo que es altamente explosivo**

No botes tu tiempo pensando en como protegerlo, conversalo en tu próximo desayuno con el presidente de los EEUU que manda la CIA hacer desaparecer los weones que te lo robaron. Probablemente te va decir que ya lo tienen organizado (o que ya esta hecho).

**2) Soy uno de los mejores expertos en el tema y desarrollo algo genial más rápido que otro podría haber hecho.**

Si es así, porque quieres botar tiempo en cosas tan aburridos como "proteger" código? Dinero es poco probable, porque con esta descripción puedes seguir adelante, generalmente te pagan lo que tu pides de todos modos.

**3) Soy bueno en lo que hago y quiero proteger lo para que he trabajado mucho tiempo**

Imaginemos que inventaste todo tu solo. En el contexto de código fuente abierto trabajan un montón de gente que son bueno en lo que tu haces y más encima trabajan en equipo. Cuando tu salgas de tu sótano con tu producto probablemente vas a encontrar con varios soluciones fuente abierto, entonces que quieres proteger? Si no hay, probablemente es un producto que nadie necesita.

**4) Me manejo en la programación, pero esta vez tuve una tremendamente buena idea**

En vez de botar tiempo en pensar como proteger tu código, deberías enfocar en remunerarlo y sacar lo máximo que posible del producto. Antes que lo copian. Lo van a hacer si es exitoso, con o sin tu código. Que producto al fin sobrevive no depende de la calidad del código, pero del marketing.

Se pueden construir muchos más casos, pero de nuevo la síntesis siempre es la misma:

**Si eres TAN creativo, no pierdes tiempo en "proteger" código, pero mantente al tope siguiendo haciendo lo que haces mejor: crear. Si todavía no lo eres, invierte tu tiempo en aprender como serlo, pero no en "proteger" código.**

¡Buenas noches! :)

Comment: La verdad que tienes razón. Minecraft se hizo en java y se podía decompilar. Incluso hay vídeos de Notch cambiando código sobre la marcha y enseñándoselo a todo el mundo. Incluso gran parte estaba accesible desde varias game jams. Al final el tío vendió a Microsoft todo para dedicarse a otras cosas. Para mí es más importante que se use tu software incluso con licencias gratis a que lo usen 4 pavos sin poder decompilarlo. Es más, si no hubiera copias piratas de Windows ¿Cuánta cuota de mercado tendrían?

Comment: "Si no hay, probablemente es un producto que nadie necesita" yo agregaría lo siguiente: "o es algo novedoso y al poco tiempo alguien lo recreará con mas características y de código abierto".

Answer (score 0):

La ofuscación de codigo es el termino clave con el cual puedes buscar informacion , yo utilizo este programa :

https://sourceforge.net/projects/javaguard/

Es bastante sencillo y evita una fácil de-compilación.

Answer (score 0):

1.- No hay protección total, si tu programa es ejecutado en una maquina externa, por su puesto que va a tener otros métodos para desencriptarlo.

2.- Por mas que protejas tu código, SIEMPRE, habrá una forma de reutilizarlo, ya que no olvides "LA PROGRAMACIÓN ES LO IMPOSIBLE DE LO IMPOSIBLE".

3.- No hay que ir muy lejos, ¿Qué ha sucedido con el software de Microsoft?, siempre dicen que es a prueba de balas y hasta este momento, no existe... no ha habido hasta ahorita un método 100% confiable, si hay métodos de cifrado para dificultarlo, pero créeme que yo no he conocido hasta ahorita a una persona que me diga que su código es a prueba de hackers.

Mi opinión muy humildemente, si hay formas que permitan dificultar el cifrado, pero, no son 100% seguros.